# apply custom where to the default $wp_query

Tags: wp-query, posts-where

I can read on the docs that if I need to perform a custom WHERE on WP_Query I need to do the following:

```
// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    // posts  30 to 60 days old
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-60 days')) . "'" . " AND post_date <= '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$query = new WP_Query( $query_string );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

**BUT** what If I need to apply such a WHERE condition on the default query? 
I already have other conditions being applied during a `pre_get_posts`, something like this:

```
function homepage_load_posts($query) {
  if ($query->is_home()) {
    $params = querystring_var('filter'); 

    $query->query_vars['post_type'] = array('blog_post', 'post', 'dossier'); 
    $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 12; 

    if ($params) {
      $valid_categories = valid_categories($params['cat']);
      $valid_formats    = valid_formats($params['format']);
      $valid_post_types = valid_post_types($params['type']);

      if ($valid_categories) $query->query_vars['cat'] = $valid_categories; 
      if ($valid_formats)    $query->query_vars['tax_query'] = $valid_formats; 
      if ($valid_post_types) $query->query_vars['post_type'] = $valid_post_types;

    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'homepage_load_posts');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `posts_where` filter should still fire. Just add it like this:

```
function homepage_load_posts($query) {
  if ($query->is_home()) {
    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
    //
```

And make the filter self-removing...

```
// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
    // posts  30 to 60 days old
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-60 days')) . "'" . " AND post_date <= '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
}
```

Comment: yes it works thanks! I suspect I was doing something wrong like using `add_action` instead of `add_filter` :\